# ORA-00922: Missing or Invalid option for SET FEEDBACK OFF in TOAD

Tags: sql, oracle, toad

I am using TOAD application to execute my query which you can see below:

```
SET FEEDBACK OFF;

SELECT * FROM TABLENAME 
-- and then rest of the queries
```

I used `SET FEEDBACK OFF` in Toad app (by Quest Software) as an alternative to `SET NOCOUNT ON` in SQL, but it shows error and says:

> ORA-00922: Missing or Invalid option

Is there any alternative to `SET NOCOUNT ON` that we write in SQL for Oracle?

Comment: `Set feedback off` is a SQL*Plus command, it will also work for SQL Developer. Both are Oracle products, Toad is not an Oracle product

Comment: According to the documentation https://support.quest.com/kb/35317/what-sql-plus-commands-are-supported-by-toad- the command `SET FEEDBACK` is supported. Perhaps you need to figure out what settings allow Toad to recognize SQL\*Plus commands.

Comment: Something easy to try (before looking for other things): SQL\*Plus commands use their own scripting language, quite different from SQL. SQL\*Plus commands are not ended in semicolon. Some interfaces simply ignore the semicolon, but others may not. Try dropping the semicolon and see what happens.

Comment: Here is a very old discussion of running SQL Plus commands in Toad. Perhaps completely out of date, but it may tell you what to look for. (Sorry, I don't use Toad - SQL Developer seems good enough to me, and it's free.) https://community.oracle.com/tech/developers/discussion/1004607/sql-plus-command-in-toad

Comment: @mathguy, dropping the semicolon does not make any difference. I had try this already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SET` set of commands - in Oracle - was originally related to its command-line tool named **SQL*Plus**. It (the `SET`) works in some other tools, such as Oracle's GUI - SQL Developer.

Mathguy showed me that TOAD recognizes quite a lot SQL*Plus commands (I thought it does not); it is the way you **run** code in TOAD:

- if you run it as a separate **command**, it won't work:

  [image]
- on the other hand, if you run it as a **script**, then it works, and the result is displayed in its "Script output" tab:

  [image]

Comment: Toad recognizes many SQL\*Plus commands. Perhaps you can describe how you came to the (incorrect) information you are sharing in this Answer.

Comment: @mathguy, I'm not sure what you meant to say. SET is a SQL Plus command. I tried several of them (VERIFY, FEEDBACK, SERVEROUTPUT, DEFINE, ...) - the outcome is just the same: **missing or invalid option** (screenshot attached). With or without trailing semi-colon. I'm not talking about "many SQL Plus commands" but **SET** (which is the issue here). Could you explain the comment, please?

Comment: I posted a link to the official Toad documentation in my comment to the OP (third comment under the original question). As you can see there, about 90% of SQL Plus commands are supported, including most of the SET commands - including, specifically, SET FEEDBACK.

Comment: Also in (another) comment I suggested trying the same without the semicolon. I explained there why, too.

Comment: I just added one more comment with a link to an old (2009) discussion of how to run SQL Plus commands in Toad. What does the Toad manual say about HOW to run SQL Plus commands?

Comment: A-ha. I see. OTN discussion made it clear, @mathguy - it is about executing code **as a script** instead of executing it as a single command. In that context, you're absolutely right. Thank you for the effort!

Comment: OK; fixed the answer, I hope it now makes sense.

Comment: @Littlefoot thanks, it worked! I find it strange that it works when executed as "Script" but not otherwise, any idea?

Comment: You're welcome (thanks go to @mathguy as well!). I don't know why TOAD works like that; perhaps you could ask on TOAD for Oracle forum (https://forums.toadworld.com/c/toad-for-oracle/10)